# Find select values on one worksheet and copy to a second

Tags: performance, array, vba

In the `Calculator` worksheet of my spreadsheet, for any appliance type present in a building being studied, users enter a quantity. There are 18 different appliance types, and users can enter different quantities of any or all appliance types.

On the `Calculator` sheet they can see a breakdown of energy use per individual appliance, per appliance type, and for all appliances with a quantity entered:

[image]

The macro below (run from a second sheet) copies specific values from `Calculator` so that they can be pasted into another spreadsheet which is used for reporting. It selects only appliance types for which the user entered a quantity.

[image]

```
Sub findAppliances()

    ' Get Range
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F5:F22")

    ' Create dynamic array
    Dim ApplianceQty As Variant

    ' Read values into array
    ApplianceQty = rg.Value

    ' Manipulate and copy the appropriate values
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    j = 4
    Dim target As String
    Dim source As String
    For i = LBound(ApplianceQty) To UBound(ApplianceQty)
        target = j
        If ApplianceQty(i, 1) <> "" Then
            source = i + 4
            Range("B" & target) = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F" & source) & " units"
            Range("F" & target) = "=F" & target - 1 & "-" & Worksheets("Calculator").Range("J" & source)
            Range("G" & target) = "=G" & target - 1 & "-" & Worksheets("Calculator").Range("K" & source)
            Range("H" & target) = "=H" & target - 1 & "-" & Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L" & source)
            Range("K" & target) = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("E" & source)
            Range("L" & target) = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("C" & source)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Select and copy the text for export
    Range("B4:M" & target).WrapText = False
    Range("B4:M" & target).Select
    Range("B4:M" & target).Copy

End Sub
```

I *suspect* that the reason this takes so long to run is the group of six `Range() = Worksheets("Calculator").Range()` lines within my `For` loop. I *further* suspect that if I read all the data I need into an array, then printed it back out of the array (rather than reading cells and copying to new cells), the whole thing would run faster.

**Is that true?** How much improvement can I expect?

Comment: That is 100% true

Comment: I suspect that the speed issue is due to a large number of worksheet formulas.  It looks like your dataset is only `18x10`.  That should be almost instantaneous.  I just posted a class that is ideal for processing your data.  Using arrays and a dictionary it takes 0.6 seconds per `10K x 7` to run. [IndexedArray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197144/171419).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - nice job declaring all of your variables. The naming could use a little work (`sourceRange`, `applianceQuantityArray`). Declaring several on the same line and giving them both a type (below) - ***A+***

> ```
> Dim i As Long, j As Long
> ```

A few standard blurbs -

> Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by
>   going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require
>   Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not
>   defined, the compiler will let you know.
>
> Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window
>   (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be
>   used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mySheet")`
>   and instead just use `mySheet`.
>
> [Standard VBA naming
>   conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx)
>   have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other
>   variables and names.

---

I do want to talk about a few variables though-

```
Dim j as Long
Dim target as String
Dim i as Long
Dim source as String
j=4
>loop i
   target=j
   source = i+4
   j=j+1
>end loop
```

This seems pretty unnecessary. I'll take this -

> ```
>  Range("B" & target) = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F" & source) & " units"
> ```

to mean that you thought you need to use a `string` to put into a range format. You don't. This does the same thing (`i` being arbitrary) -

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 3) = Sheet1.Range("F" & i + 4).value & " units"
Next
```

You'd probably benefit from just using the `.Cells(row, col)` format instead. But I digress.

---

#### Using an array

As you yourself have pointed out, using an array would be faster. It's always faster. Your loop is really difficult to read -

> ```
> Range("H" & target) = "=H" & target - 1 & "-" & Worksheets("Calculator").Range("L" & source)
> ```

(You're subtracting 1 from a `String` you realize?) It's the same as this -

```
 Sheet1.Cells(target, 8).value = Sheet1.Cells(target - 1, 8) - calcSheet.Cells(source, 12)
```

In the most basic way, say you take everything you need into an array

```
Dim calcArray As Variant
calcArray = calcsheet.Range(calcsheet.Cells(5, 3), calcsheet.Cells(22, 13))
For i = LBound(calcArray) To UBound(calcArray)
    If calcArray(i, 4) <> vbNullString Then
```

Pretty simple yeah? Just use the 2nd dimension of the variant to specify what column you're targeting (see I started at column 3 (C) so I had to use 4 (F).

Looks to me like you would need an array from the other sheet too, something like

```
Dim targetArray As Variant
targetArray = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(4, 6),Sheet1.Cells(UBound(calcArray) - 1, 9))
```

And then maybe you make a results array

```
Dim resultsArray As Variant
ReDim resultsArray(1 To UBound(calcArray), 1 To 3)
```

Now you can (roughly, this isn't perfect)

```
For i = LBound(calcArray) To UBound(calcArray)
    If calcArray(i, 4) <> vbNullString Then
        resultsArray(i, 1) = targetArray(i - 1) - calcArray(i, 8)
```

Populate that results array using what is essentially `range("F5").offset(,-1)` but in the array.

Then it would need to be printed back out. A few of them come straight from the `calcArray` hence I didn't make room in the `resultsArray` but you could.

Anyway, since the range is weird to me you'd just need to adjust it as you like. Or just declare your arrays starting in row 1 and change nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This got me where I needed to go. I used `someRange.Resize(UBound(resultsArray, 1), UBound(resultsArray, 2)) = resultsArray` for the last step. Worked like a charm!

Comment: That's great to hear!

Answer (score 2):

@Raystafarian's already commented on `.Cells` and `String` subtraction so I wont repeat it.

Making your code as easy to read as possible will help. Your `target` variable was redundant as it was only ever set `target = j` and then used. Use `j` directly and you remove the `target` variable. Now `j` starts off by being assigned a value of `4`. What does this number represent? In its present form you have a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). IMO it's better to use a constant with a name that describes what that number is, like `Const DestinationStartRow As Long = 4`. Going along with names, `j` isn't telling you what the variable is for. Whereas `destinationRow` immediately lets you know what it's doing. These small changes help reduce cognitive load making it much easier to understand what the code is doing.

Inside of your loop you're using `Range() = ...`. This is hiding an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`. If your code were to be invoked from a different sheet it would populate whatever-sheet-happened-to-be-active. Fully qualify your ranges with a worksheet object, preferably a `CodeName` property as @Raystafarian mentioned. Do this and you'll have no doubt which sheet will be populated.

There is also the implicit `Public` modifier since your [Sub Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/sub-statement) doesn't have it. If it's missing `Public`, `Private`, or `Friend` it silently assumes you wanted it to be `Public`. The same is true with the back end of the `Range` object. It's using the hidden `_Default` member without telling you. I suggest using `Value2` if you're grabbing the values. [Text vs Value vs Value2](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) best explains the differences.

For the ranges that use columns `F:H` since they are contiguous you can use `destination.Range().Resize(ColumnSize:=3).Formula = "=F ..."` to populate all 3 at once instead of individually.

Rather than repeatedly using `Range("B4:M" & target)` you can use a [with statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/with-statement), aka with block, to qualify them.

This is getting a bit speculative but it's bit me before. Your static value for `Range("F5:F22")` can pase a problem if you insert or delete a row/column that causes the range to shift. Think about using a NamedRange by going to the Formulas tab>Defined Names group>Name Manager button (Hotkey: `Alt, I, N, D`) to display the Name Manager dialog box to create one. Then in your code refer to named range and any shifting of the cells won't pose a problem.

I want to raise the possibility of possible erroneous errors using an array. Merged cells can be a pain and your baseline column has them. I tested a little with the code below and wanted to raise your attention that if you select all the baseline values `E5:E22` and then look at your variable in the View menu at top>Locals window that `foo(4)` is empty. Only the first cell in the merged cells will be populated with the information. `calculator.Cells(sourceRow, "E").MergeArea(1, 1).Value2` addresses this.

```
Public Sub TestingVariant()
    Dim foo As Variant
    foo = Selection
End Sub
```

This is the come I came up with after refactoring.

```
Public Sub findAppliances()
    Dim calculator As Worksheet
    Set calculator = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator") 'Change once worksheet codename is updated
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Set destination = ActiveSheet 'change to appropriate sheet

    Const DestinationStartRow As Long = 4
    Const RowOffsetBetweenSourceDestinationSheets As Long = 1
    Dim quantities As Range
    Set quantities = calculator.Range("F5:F22") 'can be replaced with a NamedRange
    Dim quantity As Range

    'Late binding to Tools>References>Microsoft Scripting Runtime to allow use of dictionary object
    Dim units As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
    Set units = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim baselineECMs As Object
    Set baselineECMs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim proposedECMs As Object
    Set proposedECMs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim destinationRow As Long
    Dim sourceRow As Long
    For Each quantity In quantities.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        destinationRow = DestinationStartRow + units.Count
        sourceRow = quantity.Row
        units.Add units.Count, calculator.Cells(sourceRow, "F").Value2
        baselineECMs.Add baselineECMs.Count, calculator.Cells(sourceRow, "E").MergeArea(1, 1).Value2
        proposedECMs.Add proposedECMs.Count, calculator.Cells(sourceRow, "C").Value2
        destination.Cells(destinationRow, "F").Resize(ColumnSize:=3).Formula = "=F" & destinationRow - RowOffsetBetweenSourceDestinationSheets & "-" & calculator.Cells(sourceRow, "J")
    Next

    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    destination.Cells(DestinationStartRow, "B").Resize(units.Count).Value2 = wf.Transpose(units.Items)
    destination.Cells(DestinationStartRow, "K").Resize(units.Count).Value2 = wf.Transpose(baselineECMs.Items)
    destination.Cells(DestinationStartRow, "L").Resize(units.Count).Value2 = wf.Transpose(proposedECMs.Items)

    With destination.Range(destination.Cells(DestinationStartRow, "B"), destination.Cells(DestinationStartRow + units.Count - 1, "M")) '-1 is to omit last blank row
        .WrapText = False
        .Copy
    End With
End Sub
```